# Is It Possible to NSLog C Structs (Like CGRect or CGPoint)?

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to be able to debug C structures without having to explicitly type every property that they consist of.

i.e. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
CGPoint cgPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
NSLog(@"%@",cgPoint);
```

Obviously the '%@' won't work, hence the question.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(rect));

Comment: Try LOG_EXPR from the VTPG_Common library: http://vgable.com/blog/tag/log_expr/

Answer (score 806, accepted):

You can try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cgPoint));
```

There are a number of functions [provided by UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW34) that convert the various CG structs into `NSString`s. The reason it doesn't work is because `%@` signifies an object. A `CGPoint` is a C struct (and so are `CGRect`s and `CGSize`s).

Comment: With AppKit on OS X you would need to convert to an `NSPoint` and then call `NSStringFromPoint`. For example: `NSStringFromPoint(NSPointFromCGPoint(point))`

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(rect));

Comment: Similar to UI, MK, CL prefixes which while all have meanings to it and need to import a respective .h file like :UIKit, MapKit, CoreLocation; Does the  CG prefix mean I should import anything? If not is is just a naming convention?!

Answer (score 236):

There are a few functions like:

```
NSStringFromCGPoint  
NSStringFromCGSize  
NSStringFromCGRect  
NSStringFromCGAffineTransform  
NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets
```

An example:

```
NSLog(@"rect1: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect1));
```

Comment: These are the: "single thing in all of iOS development that is most useful but least known" !!  Heh

Comment: Note: for Cocoa (OS X) development, these functions don't have "CG" in the name.

Answer (score 18):

```
NSLog(@"%@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(rect));
```

Answer (score 13):

I use the following macro to help me out with NSRect:

```
#define LogRect(RECT) NSLog(@"%s: (%0.0f, %0.0f) %0.0f x %0.0f",
    #RECT, RECT.origin.x, RECT.origin.y, RECT.size.width, RECT.size.height)
```

You could do something similar for CGPoint:

```
@define LogCGPoint(POINT) NSLog(@"%s: (%0.0f, %0.0f)",
    #POINT POINT.x, POINT.y);
```

Using it as follows:

```
LogCGPoint(cgPoint);
```

Would produce the following:

```
cgPoint: (100, 200)
```

Comment: Why not just use the built in [UIKit String Conversion Functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW34)?

Comment: I do now. Those are exatly the functions that Alex and steve posted in their answers.

Comment: Would it be worth editing the answer and **adding a note** at the top "For historic interest only...".  I always do that, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode/2530953#2530953  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492479/do-i-get-more-accurate-or-faster-accelerometer-readings-with-core-motion/5492892#5492892 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212628/whats-the-difference-between-setting-an-object-to-nil-vs-sending-it-a-release/4212826#4212826 (*"It's worth noting that this post from the previous decade, is really now only of historic interest."*) etc

Comment: This answer is still useful, despite the existence of UIKit conversion functions, because there other structs in other frameworks, which do not have NSStringFrom helpers (eg. MKCoordinateRegion).

Answer (score 10):

You can use `NSValue` for this. An **NSValue** object is a simple container for a single C or Objective-C data item. It can hold any of the scalar types such as int, float, and char, as well as pointers, structures, and object ids.

**Example:**

```
  CGPoint cgPoint = CGPointMake(10,30);
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:cgPoint]);
```

**OUTPUT :** `NSPoint: {10, 30}`

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use bellow few functions like:
First you have to convert CGPoint struct into string, see example

```
1) NSStringFromCGPoint,  
2) NSStringFromCGSize,  
3) NSStringFromCGRect,  
4) NSStringFromCGAffineTransform,  
5) NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets,
```

For example:

```
1) NSLog(@"NSStringFromCGPoint = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cgPointValue));
```

Like this...

Answer (score 5):

Since Stack Overflow’s broken RSS just resurrected this question for me, here’s my almost-general solution: [JAValueToString](https://github.com/JensAyton/JAValueToString)

This lets you write `JA_DUMP(cgPoint)` and get `cgPoint = {0, 0}` logged.

Comment: I did that and I got compile error. Sometimes address of property expression required or something

Comment: @Jim Thio: the macro is set up in such a way that the object being inspected must be an lvalue. (I can’t remember why; something about not being able to handle C strings properly otherwise.) In short, assign your property to a temporary variable, then call JA_DUMP on that.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSLog(@"%@",CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(rect));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Objective-C way to create objects from C primitives

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(1, 2, 3, 4);
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(1, 2);
NSLog(@"%@, %@",@(rect), @(size));
```

Output: NSRect: {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, NSSize: {1, 2}