# Do I get more accurate or faster accelerometer readings with Core Motion?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, core-motion

I can use this method of the Core Motion framework:

```
- (void)startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue withHandler:(CMAccelerometerHandler)handler
```

as an alternative to the

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
```

UIAccelerationDelegate method of UIKit. There, I have to specify the frequency of updates. I want to get acceleration data as fast and accurate as possible.

Is Core Motion my friend here? What's the frequency of readings I can expect from that method of Core Motion? The documentation doesn't talk about it.

Comment: It's all about mad science. We need as many readings per second as possible.

Comment: [accelerometer:didAccelerate:] is deprecated as of iOS 5.0 (cf. UIAccelerometer.h)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit!  Now that this answer is OVER A YEAR OLD, certainly it is only of historic value. At this stage, I guess, everyone should only be using CoreMotion and that's that. Hope this historic answer it helps an history students!

---

My impression is that: **CMAttitude and CMDeviceMotion** give you the benefit of **both** the accel'r and the gyro (if the gyro is present). Whereas CMAccelerometerData is **only the accel'r**. (Exactly like in the old days before Core Motion.)

My impression is that the two specific advantages of CoreMotion are:

(One) the mindboggling **convenience of having Quaternions and attitude given to you on a silver platter**

(Two) apparently, **both gyro and accel'r are used** on machines with a gyro, with **no extra work from you** ... a huge advantage.

I believe there is no actual technical difference in the quality of usage of the accelerometer per se.

Thus: if (for some reason) you want only the accel'r, and you can do the math (if relevant to your task at hand), you could use the old-school accel'r delegate.

It seems that in short, none of us will ever again use the old-school accelerometer delegate!

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your help.