# Landscape Mode ONLY for iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad

I want to create an application that doesn't use Portrait mode.

I am not sure if I need to edit the plist or have code in addition to the plist

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[Code found here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html)

> Launching in Landscape Mode
>
> Applications in iPhone OS normally
>   launch in portrait mode to match the
>   orientation of the Home screen. If you
>   have an application that runs in both
>   portrait and landscape modes, your
>   application should always launch in
>   portrait mode initially and then let
>   its view controllers rotate the
>   interface as needed based on the
>   device’s orientation. If your
>   application runs in landscape mode
>   only, however, you must perform the
>   following steps to make it launch in a
>   landscape orientation initially.
>
> - In your application’s Info.plist    file, add the `UIInterfaceOrientation`
>     key and set its value to the
>     landscape mode. For landscape
>     orientations, you can set the value
>     of this key to
>     `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`
>     or
>     `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.`
> - Lay out your views in landscape mode    and make sure that their
>     autoresizing    options are set
>     correctly.
> - Override your view controller’s    `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`
>     method and return YES only for the
>     desired landscape orientation and NO
>     for portrait orientations.

Comment: Always forget that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation step, without that your whole UI comes up sideways...

Answer (score 29):

To make your app landscape mode **only**, you should use "Supported Interface Orientations". 
(`Targets -> YourApp -> Supported Interface Orientations -> Landscape Left & Right`)

[image: Supported Interface Orientations]

You should also set the app's orientation in your app's `Info.plist` file ([image: Info.plist file]) by appending the `Supported interface orientations` key with the values `Landscape (left home button)` and `Landscape (right home button)`. [image: row's]

You may use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and/or `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` to handle orientation changes.

---

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated from **iOS 6** and out.

Returning `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft/Right` for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` should make your app "landscape":

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Also may also change your app's `Info.plist` and `View Orientation` (as explained above).

---

Additionally, I recommend changing your view's orientation to `Landscape` in the *Attributes Inspector*. [image: landscape]

Comment: This didnt exist back then but it's good to know about newer options

Answer (score 26):

You could also just shorten it all to

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

edit the plist to only support landscape, then make sure that in every uiviewcontroller/uitabbar etc., in the `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, the `return` says `return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));`.

Comment: Or even better: 

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) { return YES; } return NO;

Comment: Or even shorter: return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))

Comment: Yet more shorter without parentheses :-)