# Fix To LandScape

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod

Can i fix my application to landscape permanently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock Ipad App in Landscape mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888612/lock-ipad-app-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your application’s Info.plist file, add the UIInterfaceOrientation
key and set its value to the
landscape mode. For landscape
orientations, you can set the value
of this key to
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
or
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.

Override your view controller’s shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  method and return YES only for the
desired landscape orientation and NO
for portrait orientations.

Refer 
[Landscape Mode ONLY for iPhone or iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647786/landscape-mode-only-for-iphone-or-ipad) for more details

Comment: UIInterfaceOrientation was no option.. it was initial orientation.. but info.plist helped

Comment: Note that for iPad if you are supporting only one orientation, you should support both variants of orientation. Else it will be rejected by app store