# Lock Ipad App in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm pretty new to iOS development so please bear with me.

I am creating an app that I want to strictly be used in landscape mode.

I have edited the .plist file to include these two keys:

Initial interface orientation: Landscape (right home button) &
Supported interface orientation: Landscape (right home button)

And I've added the following code to ViewController.m:

```
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    }
```

The app currently starts as it's supposed to in the simulator. It starts up in landscape mode and everything works just fine. However, my problem comes in when press a button that takes me to another "scene". The landscape mode doesn't carry throughout the rest of the apps.

So my question is, how do I force landscape mode throughout my entire app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in each ViewController.

Comment: I might be missing something completely obvious here, but when I try to go to a specific ViewController to add code, it just shows me the ViewController.h file and not the one I want to edit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BenT. You mean trying to select a given ViewController in the project hierarchy always goes to one ViewController? Or are you using a different approach to get to them?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I may be understanding this wrong but I am trying to select a certain ViewController but it always seems to go to the same ViewController.h file. Again I may be understanding this completely wrong and I apologize.

Comment: Hmm... you should be able to go to the .m files and add the autorotate code without an issue. Maybe something's up with Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, what you need to do is put this code in every ViewController that you have.