# lock iPad to landscape orientation

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, sprite-kit

I have a game that I only want to be played in landscape mode. This is fine for iPhone but not fine for iPad. I thought I could get around this by releasing 2 versions of the same app, one for iPhone and one for iPad. However, after looking further I've found that the iPhone app needs to be iPad ready? I've seen this answer that suggests that it is possible to lock the orientation of an iPad app:

[Lock Ipad App in Landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888612/lock-ipad-app-in-landscape-mode)

Is this still possible in the later versions of xCode and swift, and if so, how??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can do. in the viewDidLoad method in every ViewController class insert this code.

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {

            // this code will be executed if the device is an iPad
          override  func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
              return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
         }

          override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
                  return false
          }

    }
```

What will happen is the following

1. The viewDidLoad function is executed and the if statement is evaluated
2. The condition for the if statement is true so the statements inside the block should be executed
3. The first override function will set the orientation to landscapeleft. You can change that to landscaperight
4. The second function will lock the orientation rotation functionality

NOTE: I prefer that you embed all your view controllers inside a navigation controller and linking this navigation controller to a class then writing the code i gave you in the viewDidLoad method of this class. This will make the configuration for all the views inside this navigation controller rather than typing them in every class

Comment: Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: Just added this to my code, and all of the views are locked to landscape perfectly, except the launchScreen.xib. How do I access the view controller  for this? Also, when the game starts it isn't set to landscape in the first scene until I move onto the next scene, BUT, if I go back onto that scene without closing the simulator it is then set to landscape.

Comment: I don't know about the launchscreen.xib but for setting landscape as soon as the game launch use viewWillLoad method instead of viewWillLoad. Please tell me if it work

Comment: I've tried viewWillLoad and and viewWillAppear but it didn't work. I'll look into it more.

Comment: Fixed it, I used the code you provided to force the iPad, and checked my p.list.. turns out supported interface orientations array had included portrait options so I deleted them and problem solved, both iPhone and iPad can be locked. More information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 3):

If one has to lock the orientation for all the screens and for iPhone and iPad, you can easily achieve the same directly in Xcode.

Go into Targets>General>Deployment Info and the select the required device orientation. Please check the screenshot.
[image]

In this way you wont have any problem with the Launch Image

Comment: The deployment info works for the iPhone but not the iPad, the iPad orientation can't usually be locked.

Comment: @kellclx are you sure? let me check again and come back to it

Comment: See my comment above, the deployment info works when the p.list is changed to remove the portrait options that remain in 'supported interface orientations' that remain even if you change the deployment info. Thank you for your help :) I found information about the p.list here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW1

Comment: **This actually works.** If it is a "universal" app, you can choose iPad for "Devices" and then set the wished rotation. Do the same for iPhone, then set it back to "universal"!

Comment: Thanks @LinusGeffarth. Not easy to realise this!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just remove the orientations you don't from info.plist under "Supported interface orientations (iPad)"

Answer (score 0):

i belive this can be done in the under deployment info in the blue file at the top of the file navigator in xcode