# Xcode: how to build a landscape only iphone program

Tags: iphone, xcode

in Xcode, I tried to design a landscape only user interface.

I both set UIViewController and UIView controls to landscape model. but when I placed the controls, like buttons, images on the UIView, when programe running, only the controls which are placed on top-left area response. Seems the programe is still running in portrait mode.

Comment: so do u want only landscape not in portrait right..

Comment: open info.plist-> supportedinterfaceorientation->add only landscape

Comment: Please visit this question for your answer: [Landscape mode only for iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647786/landscape-mode-only-for-iphone-or-ipad)

Answer (score 4):

In project plist setup `Initial interface orientation` field in `Landscape (left home button)`. Also setup `Supported interface orientations` field.

And override method `-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation` in your ViewController:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```