# Allow only landscape mode in iOS app

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, screen-orientation

I read up [Landscape Mode ONLY for iPhone or iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647786/landscape-mode-only-for-iphone-or-ipad) and followed the steps, the app opens up in landscape mode but whenever i reallocate the view, it again comes up in the portrait mode. I have kept Landscape right as the only supported resolution and have overridden the souldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation as well. I am working on iOS 5.1.

Thanks.

Code:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: Add your code please(interface orientaton)

Comment: Did you do this? `Targets -> YourApp -> Supported Device Orientations -> Click only on Landscape Right (make it darker than the rest)`

Comment: Yes. I could solve the problem temporarily now. I was reallocating the views, which created problems. Now, I am removing all sub-views and writing on the original view again.

Comment: its not working. If you lock/unlock orientation switch in your device (in bottom drawer menu) then you will have portrait even if the app can only do landscape.