# x Position on 4 inch retina display is off the screen

Tags: ios, frame, retina-display

I am busy creating a view from scratch and have run into a problem I have never run in to before. I am developing on a 4 inch retina screen on an app that is landscape mode only. The problem I am having is that the width of the view is **568 points** (as it should be), but if I place an item at **xpos 280 points**, it is half off the screen!

The code I am using to create the frame is is:

```
CGRectMake(280, 9, 100, 13);
```

Here is a screenshot of the result. The view in question has a red background color and is off the screen on the right:
http://cl.ly/image/2U333e1W300l

*Edit - the width in this case seems to be 284 points, which is exactly half of 568 (the supposed width). So it seems the width is only half of what it should be... strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the answer.

The problem was that I was not initialising the app to startup in landscape mode properly. After following the instructions in this post: [Landscape Mode ONLY for iPhone or iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647786/landscape-mode-only-for-iphone-or-ipad/6776804#6776804) . My problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

When you use this:

```
CGRectMake(280, 9, 100, 13);
```

You use points, not pixel.

1 point = 2 pixels.

The width of the screen is 320 points. Therefore, your view is placed 40points (80 pixels) before the view ends.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I meant "points" - I will edit my post. But your answer still does not solve my problem. In landscape width is 568 points and height is 320 points

Answer (score 0):

Probably auto-layout (autoresizing mask's) moves the view. Can you set frame explicitly for the view after rotation? If it will work, then you should take a look to auto-layout (or auto-resizing mask's).

Comment: The view does not rotate as the app is locked in landscape mode so unfortunately this is not an auto-layout issue

Comment: If you are saying that at the beginning the frame is correct and something change it somewhere in the middle. Then just do e.g. a KVO for ``frame`` key path, and you will see who changes it. Maybe even a superview has a wrong frame, or a superview of a superview. You also can set a breakpoint in e.g. ``-viewDidAppear`` and in lldb terminal execute ``po [yourView recursiveDescription]``.

Comment: I ran the command and it showed that nothing had changed the rect at all. It's not that the xpos is incorrect. It's almost as if the width of the view is a 50% or something

Comment: You should check all view tree, e.g. you can run ``po [view recursiveDescription]`` then ``po [[view superview] recursiveDescription]``, ``po [[[view superview] superview] recursiveDescription]`` and so on. Then you should be able to discover , which of the view has wrong frame.

Comment: I ran those commands too and the frame is the correct width (568) and does not ever change

Comment: Width is just one part, you also should take a look to frames origins.