# iphone device orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, orientation

During inAppPurchase, the storeKit will ask the username and password

even though i set...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

It ask Username and password in Portrait Mode... **In general How to solve this kind of issue**.

*UPDATED : But the InAppPurchase message on successful purchase is coming in landscape mode.*

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does your view controller implement shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation: ?  What do you return for portrait & upsidedown?

Comment: I am not using view controller... thats why [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]; has no effect on it.

Comment: I tried by adding view controller, and in delegate shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation i returned YES for  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight... But the login dialog from apple ask username and password in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.2 you cannot change the orientation of a running application from code.

But you can start an application with a fixed orientation, although doing so this is not straightforward.

Try with this recipe:

1. set your orientation to `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` in the `Info.plist` file
2. in your window define a 480x320 "base view" every other view will be added to
3. in all view controllers set up the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method (to return the same value you defined in the plist, of course)
4. in all view controllers set a background view with

   `self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)`

   in the `viewDidLoad` method that should do the trick.

References:

- http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7366-interface-builder-landscape-design.html#post186977
- http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7366-interface-builder-landscape-design.html#post190014
- [iPhone app in landscape mode, 2008 systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your entire application in landscape from the Info.plist?

Comment: Yes i setted to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.