# iPhone - Landscape Only App

Tags: iphone, landscape

I am trying to make an app that will only be viewed in Landscape. I have looked up some tutorials (albeit older ones) and have done the following:
  -set up the info.plist to include a key for uiinterfaceorientation
  -in the main view controller I have set the frame to be 480 x 320

Now, the first screen loads up ok. Everything is where it should be and whatnot. However, if I click a button that is set to present a modal view controller nothing happens. Everything is linked and coded correctly but nothing happens when I press the button. Am I doing something wrong with trying to force landscape?

At it's basic, this question is a how do you effectively make an app that will only be in landscape mode? Thanks for any help.

Comment: repeat.. hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode

Answer (score 0):

You should only uncomment this method I show you below:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```