# Always open a view in portrait mode in view in ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation

When I navigate from one view to another view, I want to open the view in portrait view only.ie I am navigating from a first view (landscape) to second view. I want the second view to always be open in portrait view.In my case when I launch in landscape, the view is in portrait but the device is in landscape mode. The output I expected was if I open the view in portrait  and and on rotating it to landscape with no rotation.

EDIT:

If you open the app in portrait and if you given auto-rotate as NO.Then if you rotate the device to landscape,then there will be no rotation in output.I want the same effect when loading a view initially in landscape.

Comment: Watch out for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot use `setOrientation` anymore, since it is deprecated and apps have been declined for using it.

This may be an option for you:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/33548-alternative-setorientation.html

It rotates the view using a transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what you want to do is edit one of the functions in the view file.  You want to set;

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;
}
```

From return YES to return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

Then your view should only be in potrait.

Comment: this delegate is called when the orientation changed while displaying the view/viewcontroller. Will not be called if you navigate from a landscape view.

Comment: the view is created in portrait frame that appears in landscape view.

Comment: If you open the app in portrait and if you given auto-rotate as NO.then if you rotate the device to landscape,then there will be no rotation in output.i want the same effect when loading a view intially in landscape.