# How to change the orientation to landscape right if the device is iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to know how to change the orientation to landscape right if the device is iPad. I am doing this app for both ipad and iphone. If it is iPhone the screen should be in portrait mode if its ipad the screen should be in landscape right.

Can anybody help how to do this, thanks

Comment: at the time the popular QA on this purely historic issue was: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2530953/294884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my previous post:

[Always open a view in potrait mode in view in ipad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133280/always-open-a-view-in-potrait-mode-in-view-in-ipad/4134143#4134143)