# Different Launch orientations for iPad and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, orientation

I'm making a universal app and I was wondering if it is possible to set initial orientation to Landscape for iPad and Portrait for iPhone? Currently, I'm setting `initial interface orientation` in the `info.plist` file but it doesn't seem to have different options for iPad and iPhone . If it cannot be done through `info.plist` file then how to do it programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628668/468724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `initial interface orientation` property conflicts with the `supported orientation`s. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode), though.

Answer (score 1):

programatically you can do using following code -

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            return YES;
        } 

    }
    else {

        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

return NO;
```

}

Comment: I found the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode

Comment: This is not the solution I was looking for, my friend...The issue is with launch orientation(when iOS has not begun with orientation notifications, so that `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is **not** called). If you `NSLog` the device orientation in your appdelegate, you'll get the output as `orientation unknown`!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    }
```

Comment: `setOrientation` can get my app rejected. Thanks anyway