# How to make xcode ios app not view vertically

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, landscape-portrait

so, i have an ios app and i have built it with interface builder and xcode. I built it using interface builder in the horizontal view because that is how i want my app. I have also made the supported views landscape left and right and i have edited info.plist to make it open horizontally.

But when i build and go it opens in iphone simulator horizontally but it shows as it would if it was vertical.

here's some screenshots:
what i want it to look like:
http://www.sendspace.com/file/4ct4b0

what it actually looks like:
http://www.sendspace.com/file/fayjqj

how could i get it to open like i want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow the orientation also in your implementation of `UIViewController` using `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
         return YES; //or UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation) for just landscape
 }
```

Also, if you have some more problems look on linked SO questions to this "out-dated" question:
[iPhone app in landscape mode, 2008 systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode)